# drop pin with long touch in google maps

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, marker

i can't add marker with long touch in google maps in swift 
i have try lots of codes but it doesn't work for me
what should i do !?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()        
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyBw95wEhcSiSBmPWuYkiK0_IBnZQK-Lm7I")


    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
    print("Error" + error.description)
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let userLocation = locations.last
    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: userLocation!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: userLocation!.coordinate.longitude)

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(userLocation!.coordinate.latitude,
                                                      longitude: userLocation!.coordinate.longitude, zoom: 16)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
    mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
    mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
    view = mapView

   let  position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(10, 10)
    let marker = GMSMarker(position: position)


    marker.opacity = 0.6
    marker.position = center
    marker.title = "Current Location"
    marker.snippet = ""
    marker.map = mapView
    //mapView.clear()
}
```

Ant help would be appreciate

Comment: you want to drag existing marker or want to add a new marker on map?

Comment: new marker ! for destination

Comment: You want to add marker on long press not on single tap on mapview.

Comment: yes! now what should i do !? what is the code for it ?!

Comment: Try my answer and let me know it is working or not.

Answer (score 2):

Have you try this. First you need to add long gesture on mapView like this

For Objective C

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
[self.mapView addGestureRecognizer:self.longPress];
```

Now add this handleLongPress function

```
- (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        CGPoint longPressPoint = [recognizer locationInView:self.mapView];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [mapView.projection coordinateForPoint: point];
        //Now you have Coordinate of map add marker on that location
     }
}
```

For swift

```
let longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(("handleLongPress:")))
self.mapView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)
```

Now add this handleLongPress function

```
@objc func handleLongPress(recognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer)
 {
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began)
    {
        let longPressPoint = recognizer.location(in: self.mapView);
        let coordinate = mapView.projection.coordinate(for: longPressPoint )
        //Now you have Coordinate of map add marker on that location
        let marker = GMSMarker(position: coordinate)
        marker.opacity = 0.6
        marker.title = "Current Location"
        marker.snippet = ""
        marker.map = mapView
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: i have to change it to swift first !

Comment: Sry i didn't notic you want the code in swift. Let me edit my answer in swift

Comment: No method declared with Objective-C selector 'handleLongPress:'

Comment: Is it run time or compile time?

Comment: Check my answer in this page !

Comment: You are doing this wrong way. you need to add gestures 2 lines in viewdidload. And then create a function of that method not inside any other function. Have you got it?

Comment: let longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleLongPress:")
self.mapView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)

Comment: add this two line in viewDidLoad() method. and create that function inside your viewController not inside any other function.

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Where you getting that error? On coordinate. Try to print coordinate  before use it.

Comment: Have you try to print the value of coordinate after you get from mapView method.

Comment: print(coordinate) like that. Can you show me the screen shot of your code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37762422/fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-value-lldb

Comment: Why you have added gesture in location method i told you put that line in viewDidLoad()

Comment: check that page again

Comment: self.View.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)

Comment: Have you write the code of add marker inside that gesture method?

Comment: Getting crash in this line : CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [mapView.projection coordinateForPoint: longPressPoint];

Comment: -[MKMapView projection]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8ac140b850
2017-03-13 16:19:26.239 geofences[2914:155187] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MKMapView projection]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8ac140b850'

Comment: @MihirOza This answer is for google map not for the Apple Mapkit.

Comment: I used google map but in crash log it showing like that. Anyway thanks I got my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a big deal for now by google map provide an override function with a long press. Here is an example code:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didLongPressAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    let marker = GMSMarker(position: coordinate)
   marker.icon = UIImage(named: "ic_pin_marker") // custom your own marker
   marker.map = mapView
}
```