# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, marker

I'm trying to add marker in google maps with long touch in swift !!!!!
and when i add below code some errors raised !

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    var mapView: GMSMapView?
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var locationMarker: GMSMarker!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.handleLongPress(_:)))
        self.mapView!.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)

        GMSServices.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyBw95wEhcSiSBmPWuYkiK0_IBnZQK-Lm7I")


        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        print("Error" + error.description)
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let userLocation = locations.last
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: userLocation!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: userLocation!.coordinate.longitude)

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(userLocation!.coordinate.latitude,
                                                          longitude: userLocation!.coordinate.longitude, zoom: 16)
        let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
        mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
        mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
        view = mapView

 // marker with optional position
       let  position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(10, 10)
        let marker = GMSMarker(position: position)


        marker.opacity = 0.6
        marker.position = center
        marker.title = "Current Location"
        marker.snippet = ""
        marker.map = mapView
        //mapView.clear()
        //locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

        }
    func handleLongPress(recognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer)
    {
        if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began)
        {
            let longPressPoint = recognizer.locationInView(self.mapView);
            let coordinate = mapView!.projection.coordinateForPoint(longPressPoint )
            //Now you have Coordinate of map add marker on that location

        }}


    }
```

[You can see error page here !!!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKPay.jpg)

Comment: you can add breakpoints at viewDidLoad & didUpdateLocations to know exactly where the nil optional exists

Comment: Check if in didUpdateLocations delegate method, userlocation is nil or not

Comment: error is in view did load ()

Comment: You are wrapping mapView and adding UILongPressGestureRecognizer on it. And you are initializing mapView in didUpdateLocations . That's your problem by which you are getting error. 
Use this code:
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you use map view without it is being initialized

```
var mapView: GMSMapView?
```

in viewDidLoad

```
    self.mapView!.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)
```

Comment: what should i change ?!

Comment: self.view.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)

Comment: var position = coordinate
        var marker = GMSMarker(position: position)
        marker.title = "Test Marker"
        marker.map = mapView

Comment: please mark this answer as true & try this ::    var tempMapSubView = self.views[0] as! GMSMapView
marker.map = tempMapSubView

Comment: Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'views'

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36859024/gmsmarker-not-appearing-on-map
&& http://iosallinone.blogspot.com.eg/2015/04/a-swift-tutorial-for-google-maps-sdk.html

Answer (score 1):

Error is raised in didUpdateLocations methods because its seems that sometimes we are not getting location so its passing nil on there.

So you can used try catch block or either use If let syntax to avoid this problem.

Comment: didUpdateLocations don't get called unless it have locations and it can never be nil